# MySQL challenge using MIN and subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

My intent is to return a date value based on a selected year as well as a minimum date value based on a dataset that includes the complete dataset across all years.  The query always returns the minimum date value in 2017.  I want it to return the minimum start_date from the whole dataset.

What I get is for min_date_over_all_years

```
orgA    2017-10-09
orgB    2017-10-08
```

Required result for min_date_over_all_years is

```
orgA        2015-10-10 
orgB        2014-10-09
```

Please see the attached fiddle for the example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0f74/9

The schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `organisation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `project` (`project_id`, `p_name`, 
`start_date`, `organisation_id`)
VALUES
(1, 'testP1', '2017-10-09', 1),
(2, 'testP2', '2016-10-10', 1),
(3, 'testP3', '2015-10-10', 1),
(4, 'testP4', '2017-10-10', 2),
(5, 'testP5', '2014-10-10', 2),
(6, 'testP6', '2017-10-10', 1),
(7, 'testP7', '2016-10-10', 1),
(8, 'testP8', '2015-10-10', 1),
(9, 'testP9', '2017-10-08', 2),
(10, 'testP10', '2014-10-09', 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `organisation` (`organisation_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`org_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`organisation_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `organisation` (`organisation_id`, `org_name` 
)
 VALUES
(1, 'orgA'),
(2, 'orgB');
```

AND the query I have tried (along with simpler subquery and Case versions) is:

```
SELECT o.org_name, MIN(p.start_date) AS min_date_2017, YEAR(p.start_date) AS year_selected,
(SELECT MIN(p.start_date) FROM project p2
INNER JOIN organisation o2 ON o2.organisation_id = p2.organisation_id
 WHERE p2.organisation_id = o.organisation_id
GROUP BY o2.organisation_id) AS min_date_over_all_years
FROM organisation o
INNER JOIN project p on p.organisation_id = o.organisation_id
WHERE YEAR(p.start_date)=2017
GROUP BY o.organisation_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a subquery that returns multiple rows in the `SELECT` list; when a subquery is being used as an expression, it has to return a single row with a single column.

You don't need a separate query.

```
SELECT o.org_name,
        MIN(IF(YEAR(p.start_date) = 2017, p.start_date, NULL)) AS min_date_2017,
        2017 AS year_selected,
        MIN(p.start_date) AS min_date_over_all_years
FROM organisation AS o
INNER JOIN project AS p ON p.organisation_id = o.organisation_id
GROUP BY o.organisation_id
```

You can also join with a subquery that gets the overall data.

```
SELECT o.org_name, MIN(p.start_date) AS min_date_2017, YEAR(p.start_date) AS year_selected, overall.start_date AS min_date_over_all_years
FROM organisation o
INNER JOIN project p on p.organisation_id = o.organisation_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT organisation_id, MIN(start_date) AS start_date
    FROM project 
    GROUP BY organisation_id) AS overall ON o.organisation_id = overall.organisation_id
WHERE YEAR(p.start_date)=2017
GROUP BY o.organisation_id
```

Comment: Thank you - but (I think) the WHERE clause overall is important as I want to return other summary data for example SUM(invoice_value) based on the clause  "WHERE  YEAR(p.start_date) = 2017"  There would be many fields based on this clause and only the one based on the full dataset?

Comment: I've added a second solution that joins with a subquery that gets the overall data.

Comment: Perfect Barmar - thank you for such a speedy response - really appreciated

Comment: And all of this was to create a view - which do not allow subqueries in the FROM statement.  he ho - I believe the answer is to create a second view with the subquery data in it and then link to the first ... - again thank you Barmar

Comment: again thank you Barmar for the solution - I understand something new about how two link two datasets...